# Keyboard hotkey to restore VirtualBox window?

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, window-restore

Not sure why, but in my latest custom VM the bar with the `- □ ❌` is permanently hidden…

All I configured was for it to appear in the top center (like VMware), I didn't configure it to disappear :\

**How do I configure a hotkey to automatically restore the VM window?**

(or just to make it reappear, like in [ticket 923](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/923))

Comment: And yes, I have tried hovering my mouse to the top (and bottom) center

Comment: Have you tried the (right-)Ctrl+F for Fullscreen toggle.